WTelegramClient using clients from files.session
I have file.session how to use it in WtelegramClient.
What is written about this in the documentation: https://github.com/wiz0u/WTelegramClient/blob/master/FAQ.md#2-how-to-handle-multiple-user-accounts
 string Config(string what)
    {
        switch (what)
        {   
            case "api_id": return Properties.Settings.Default.api_id;
            case "api_hash": return Properties.Settings.Default.api_hash;
            case "phone_number": return Properties.Settings.Default.phone_number;
            case "session_pathname": return "sessions/filename.session";
            case "verification_code":
            case "password":
                BeginInvoke(new Action(() => CodeNeeded(what.Replace('_', ' '))));
                _codeReady.Reset();
                _codeReady.Wait();
                return textBoxCode.Text;
            default: return null;
        };

    }

public static WTelegram.Client client = new WTelegram.Client(what => Config(what));

